# How to acquire and analyze historical market data from finviz.com

Tags: python, pandas

How can I acquire, summarize, clean and explore, generate relative valuations from stock market data from https://finviz.com? I also need to screen and analyze the historical prices using python.

I haven't done much. I am relatively new to data science so I do not knoow much how to proceed. I tried to just load the url into the pandas csv reader but it threw an error.

```py
import pandas as pd.

finviz = pd.read_csv('https://finviz.com')
finviz.head(5)
```

I expected a complete CSV file from the site with stock data.

reusulting error:

> ParserError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in 
>   ----> 1 finviz = pd.read_csv('http://finviz.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`read_html`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) for list of DataFrames, so e.g. for select `6.th` table use `[5]`, because pythoun counts from `0`, also if necessary remove column `Unnamed: 4`:

```
df = pd.read_html('https://finviz.com', header=0)[5].drop('Unnamed: 4', axis=1) 
print (df)
   Ticker    Last  Change    Volume           Signal
0    EVER   19.70  49.24%   3196642      Top Gainers
1     IVC    5.62  34.77%   1377981      Top Gainers
2    NPTN    5.82  34.72%  12112343      Top Gainers
3    ADNT   25.45  31.87%   5180011      Top Gainers
4    LONE    2.97  28.02%   1891073      Top Gainers
5    FLGT   10.26  27.45%    307509      Top Gainers
6    FLGT   10.26  27.45%    307509         New High
7    PODD  143.13  21.37%   2519748         New High
8    ALLK   79.47  21.77%   3952570         New High
9    EVER   19.70  49.24%   3196642         New High
10   SKIS   10.87  -0.09%    323809       Overbought
11   DRRX    1.44  13.39%   2846590       Overbought
12    SCC   15.29  -1.55%    143005   Unusual Volume
13   FTXG   20.23  -0.59%     85471   Unusual Volume
14   DVOL   21.82   1.49%   1876395   Unusual Volume
15   TKKS   10.07   0.00%    925400   Unusual Volume
16    AIV   50.05   2.58%   1264143         Upgrades
17    ACM   33.40  -0.12%   1472435  Earnings Before
18     CC   14.01   1.67%   4361663   Insider Buying
```

Comment: what if the website https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=152&c= has like 385 tables arranged differently. How do you download and concatenate them all?

Comment: @jazrael if you open this link http://web.mta.info/developers/turnstile.html, you'll find a series of tables, each on a different page. I want to grab them all and load it into a pandas dataframe.

Comment: @Yano - not so easy, need graf html links by BeautifulSoup to list and then in loop and create list of dataframes by `pd.read_csv('http://web.mta.info/developers/data/nyct/turnstile/turnstile_110219.txt', header=None)`, last use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)